# links will not work in fixed nav bar

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, menu, anchor

I am currently working on a page with a scrolling nav bar.  The bar scrolls fine.  However, when I try to have it link to other content, it doesn't work.  In fact, the hover effect won't work.  The page is up here: http://www.jescdesigns.com/clients/rp/

Once you scroll down past the social media icons, the nav bar appears, as I want.  When you hover over the links, the home link does not change color and will not go to Facebook and the about link will change color once I've uploaded it to the web but the link still does not work.  I feel like I'm going crazy and have tried changing the id of the anchors but that still wouldn't explain why the Facebook link will not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

My code can be found here: http://bit.ly/1S4X0zu I'm sorry about how it's setup in there, but I just created an account and I'm not too familiar with how to have the jquery work in there and I felt that was the easiest way to show my code without making this the longest page possible.

Comment: Share your code here. You need to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here in your javascript:

```
$('#menu a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

e.preventDefault(); on an anchor tag prevents links from opening.

Answer (score 0):

there's a problem in your css:

your link problem has something to do with your jquery event `e.preventDefault()`. remove that and it'll work!

add this code:

```
p.menu_left a {
    color: white;
}
```

adn remove the color:white on this css:

```
#menu a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
/* color: #FFF; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There following things prevent you change color and not allow to go to link on click.

First you have visited link set color `#FFF` so, it is display always white for home as it visited link and other link does not because other anchor tag does not have url. You need to remove it.

```
#menu a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF; //Here.
}
```

Second in your live link you have been prevented following things to to go to `facebook.com`.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank">HOME</a>
```

this should be

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">HOME</a>
```

Here `target="blank"` should be `target="_blank"`.

And in JSfiddle `e.preventDefault();` also prevent to go to `facebook.com`

```
$('#menu a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
   // e.preventDefault(); //Remove it
  });
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/356csrdf/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assign some class to the menu item which you want to exclude from being prevented default action and then add a not selector operator in the jquery like below.
I have added newClass to those anchor tags which I want to function as it is.

`$('#menu a, #fixedbar a').not(".newClass").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});`

e.preventDefault(); on an anchor tag prevents links from opening.

For example, add class="newClass" to the anchor tag of HOME.